# Access to static row from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I'm trying to access to a `UITableViewCell` from my `ViewController`

**ViewController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let sideBar = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuTV") as! SideMenuTableView
         sideBar.CellStatic.isHidden = true
}
```

**SideMenuTableView**

```
class SideMenuTableView: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var CellStatic: UITableViewCell!
    //..ALL THE CODE
}
```

But, when I try to access to my `CellStatic` to hidden it, the value is `nil`.
How I can hide the cell from my `ViewController` ?

Comment: Have your tried removing ```weak```?

Comment: @iWheelBuy the same happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `@IBOutlet` property has simply not been linked at the time you set it hidden. Try setting it to hidden in the `didSet` of the variable like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var CellStatic: UITableViewCell! {
    didSet {
        CellStatic.isHidden = true
    }
}
```